# Align dropdown menu title to dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not very experienced on web development and have run across some issue formating a list of dropdown menus and a title on top of each one.
I get this:

[image]

And I'm trying to get something like this:

[image]

This is the code I've written.

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="row" align="center" id="filtros">
                <div class="col-md-3">1. Cerca de tí
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            Todas las delegaciones
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">2. ITS
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            Todas las delegaciones
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make div as display:inline-block by this you can achieve your expected markup

check this snippet

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 .col-md-3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" align="center" id="filtros">
  <div class="col-md-3">1. Cerca de tí
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Todas las delegaciones
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">2. ITS
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Todas las delegaciones
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps